# Azure SDK Install Incompatible with Nuget

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, nuget

I'm trying to install the Azure SDK for VS2010 SP1 (latest) (26 October 2012)

When I click the Install button, I get the error:

You have a newer version of Nuget installed that's incompatible with ASP.Net MVC 3 Tools update.
To continue installing the product please refer to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=266638

That link sent me to www.asp.net/mvc which had nothing on this topic.

Is there a solution?

EF

Comment: One workaround is to uninstall Nuget, then install the Azure SDK

Comment: For what it's worth, I see a new installer for VS2010 SP1 released 2/14/2013.

Comment: Uninstalling Nuget worked.  thx.

Comment: @gdc - totally unrelated information. The OP wants the Azure SDK for VS2010 SP1, not the VS2010 SP1 package.

Comment: I had to uninstall the "Microsoft NuGet for Visual Studio 2010" from Programs and Features in Control Panel to get it to bypass the error. Uninstalling NuGet from Visual Studio 2010 (and all of the other versions) via Tools > Extension Manager did not work.

Answer (score 4):

Same issue here.

You can resolve it by clicking through this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj161045

Which will download a small temp file

Click that file which will launch the web installer.

Click install.

At that point, you'll see the error message and the I Accept button will be grayed out.

In small print at the bottom of the scroll window, you'll see a direct download link.  Click it.  As of 2013-06-26, it took me to this url: [Direct Download Link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=270081)
go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=270081

There I was able to download the msi file "WebPublishVS2010Tools.smi".  This file installs Microsoft WebPublish Visual Studio 2010.

As to whether that is the extent of the issues with installation, I don't know...

Comment: This gave me the workaround for other packages (i.e. ASP.NET MVC 3) via Web PI that complain about Nuget versions. Just look for the Direct Download link and use that.

Comment: This information was entirely unhelpful because there are no direct download links at the suggested locations. Googling turned up "Windows Azure SDK and Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio (March 2011)", which does not contain the Web Publish functionality for VS2010, which is all I was after. Web PI appears to be the only way to install it.